# Combinations meeting criteria in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, criteria

I have a dict of names and numbers ranging from 700 to 2500, and I want to combine them in a new list where the sum of the group don't go over 4500. Then I'll pick the one with least amount of entries.

I know I can make a list of all possible combinations then delete the entries that goes past the 4500, but that would make far too many unusable items.

Any hint?

Update:
Thanks to @Andrea de Marco I have part of the problem.

With the knapsack function now I have the best entry, but not all entries are in the list. So I have to run the function n times until the list is empty.

Since I'm not using any 'value' for the problem I set the value to 1.

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly?: You want to find the smallest subset of `n` numbers between `700` and `2500`, such that the sum of its elements is smaller than `4500`? This would be trivial, it is the subset consisting of only one number. (Or the empty set depending on definition). I guess I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem in literature is called **knapsack problem**

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20569/dynamic-programming-solution-to-knapsack-problem

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem/0-1

https://sites.google.com/site/mikescoderama/Home/0-1-knapsack-problem-in-p

Comment: Wow, didn't know about this problem. It's exacly what I looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with different combinations of items, you want [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html). This will allow you to generate all the possible combinations of items without actually filling your memory by building the whole lot at once. You will probably find this recipe useful:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

You can use this to generate all the combinations of the `values()` in your dictionary.

Assuming that you want to get as close as possible to some `target` but with as few values as possible, you could try:

```
best = None
for set_ in powerset(d.values()):
    if best is None and sum(set_) <= target:
        best = set_
    elif (sum(best) < sum(set_) <= target or # closer or
          (sum(best) == sum(set_) and # as close and 
           len(set_) < len(best))): # shorter
        best = set_
```

However, note that this naïve brute force approach is incredibly slow as `len(d.values())` gets larger; the number of subsets in the powerset of set `S` is `2**n`, where `n == len(S)`.